# php select option name and value

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

this is my coding

```
$sql="SELECT code,rate, name FROM price_detail WHERE ref_no='VACC'"; 

echo "<select   onchange='vaccines(this)' name='student' value='0'><option> Select Vaccines Type</option>";

foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){
            echo "<option value=$row[rate]>$row[name]</option>"; 
                    }
echo "</select>";
```

here i need $row['name'] 
for $row['rate'] i take values of option 
how can i retrive ['name']

Answer (score 0):

You can't use table notation directly into string.
You can use concatenation like this :

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['rate'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
```

Or wrap your table variables between `{}`

```
echo "<option value='{$row['rate']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
```

Don't forget the quotes for the html `value` parameter, and the quotes for the index of the table.

Note : If you don't use quotes for the table index, it will try to match a constant and will fallback assuming it is a string if no constant has been found.

Comment: Doesn't look very safe though

Comment: safe ? Can you explain why ?

Comment: It's not safe from injections as far as I can see

Comment: i'm using value $row['rate'] for insert into table.how can i use $row['name']

Comment: @SinanSamet Try to see farther then. There's no variable used in the query... ;)

Comment: @parthiban What is the actual problem ?

Comment: Well maybe I'm wrong, but as far as I know an option field would be most likely in a form and the value could be changed with for example firebug.

Comment: That does not tell anything about security. We don't have the code that handles the post. A form is not safe or not ; it is the serverside code that can have security holes.

Comment: Well okay I can agree on that